# MongoDB aggregate using scan for join collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aws-documentdb

I have two collection one collection is 'image' and other thing is 'map' for mapping info with artists

image collection has idx(single index) and map collection has multiple index(m_idx, i_idx)

i know mongodb is not RDBMS but i'm using this two table with aggregate pipline but i worried when aggregate image table, mongodb get image row by querying with index or select after scan all image collection.

i heard aggregate join the row after get all collection. but i'm not sure ..

add my query and explain result

**Query**

```
db.map.aggregate(
    [
        {
          $match: {m_idx: 1111}
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "image",
            localField: "i_idx",
            foreignField: "idx",
            as: "image_aggre"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            'image': {
              $ne: []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            seq: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $skip: (pageNum) * pageSize
        },
        {
          $limit: pageSize
        }
    ], {
        explain: true
        }
    )
```

**Explain Result**

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "db.map",
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT_SKIP",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "seq" : -1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SUBSCAN",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "HASH_AGGREGATE",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "HASH_LOOKUP",
                        "inputStages" : [
                            {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN"
                            },
                            {
                                "stage" : "HASH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "indexName" : "m_idx_-1_i_idx_-1",
                                    "direction" : "forward"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

i'm using aws-documentDB so result can be a little bit different

Comment: It usually depends upon the query you have written you can try appending [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) at the end of your query to get a clear view.

Comment: Thank you i check explain result but  i don't know which stage means join